# Run command in detached tmux session

Tags: shell, tmux

This is probably simple, but I really can't find out how you do it. I have read the man pages and googled without results.

Problem: How do I run a command in a detached tmux window?

Example: I want my detached window 'foo' to run 'ls', but I want to do it from another terminal.

I've tried stuff like: 'tmux -t foo ls' without results.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The command is `send`. `send` is a key sequence, so treat it accordingly (e.g. you'll probably want `ENTER`). The target is specified with `-t`. You may want foo.0 or foo.1 depending on the pane you wish to hit.

`tmux send -t foo.0 ls ENTER`

`send` is short for `send-keys`, which is located in the man pages, but perhaps a bit difficult to find in that mile of text.

Comment: Great answer. Very informative and works a charm. Thanks!

Comment: The most majestic solution for this issue! Massive thanks!

Comment: Note that to target a specific window in a specific session, you separate them with a colon => `tmux send-keys -t foosession:foo.0 ls ENTER`

Comment: If you want to send spaces between words, you should surround the command with two apostrophes. The ENTER command should still be outside. This works for me on UBUNTU 16.04: `tmux send -t session_name 'echo durp'` ENTER